# Android Jetpack Glance 1.0.0 : problems updating widget

Tags: android, android-widget, glance-appwidget, glance

I am implementing my first Jetpack Glance powered app widget for a simple todo list app I'm working on. I'm following the guide at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/glance and everything is fine until I get to the point where I need to update my widget to match the data updates that occured from within my application.

From my understanding of [Manage and update GlanceAppWidget](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/glance/glance-app-widget), one can trigger the widget recomposition by calling either of `update`, `updateIf` or `updateAll` methods on a widget instance from the application code itself. Specifically, calls to those functions should trigger the `GlanceAppWidget.provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId)` method, which is responsible for fetching any required data and providing the widget content, as described on this snippet :

```
class MyAppWidget : GlanceAppWidget() {

    override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {

        // In this method, load data needed to render the AppWidget.
        // Use `withContext` to switch to another thread for long running
        // operations.

        provideContent {
            // create your AppWidget here
            Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
}
```

But in my case, it is not always working. Here is what I observed after a few tries :

- It always works when first adding the widget to my dashboard. Data is always fresh there.
- It always works the first time the update method is called from the application itself (I'm using `updateAll`). The widget is updated and shows up-to-date data,
- Then it does not work if I call the update method **too soon after the last call**. In this case the `provideGlance` method is not triggered at all.

I then looked into the `GlanceAppWidget` source code and noticed it relies on an `AppWidgetSession` class :

```
    /**
     * Internal version of [update], to be used by the broadcast receiver directly.
     */
    internal suspend fun update(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetId: Int,
        options: Bundle? = null,
    ) {
        Tracing.beginGlanceAppWidgetUpdate()
        val glanceId = AppWidgetId(appWidgetId)
        if (!sessionManager.isSessionRunning(context, glanceId.toSessionKey())) {
            sessionManager.startSession(context, AppWidgetSession(this, glanceId, options))
        } else {
            val session = sessionManager.getSession(glanceId.toSessionKey()) as AppWidgetSession
            session.updateGlance()
        }
    }
```

If a session is running, it will be used to trigger the glance widget update. Otherwise it will be started and used for the same purpose.

I noticed that my problem occurs if and only if only a session is running, which would explain why it doesn't occur if I give it enough time between updates call : there are no more running sessions (whatever it means exactly) and a new one needs to be created.

I tried digging further in Glance internals to understand why it does not work when using a running session, with no success so far. The only thing I noticed and thought is weird is that at some point the `AppWidgetSession` internaly uses a class called `GlanceStateDefinition`, that I didn't see mentionned on the official Android Glance guide but that a few other guides on the web use to implement a Glance widget (Though using alpha or beta versions of Jetpack Glance libs).

Does anyone has a clue on why it behaves like this ? Here is some more information, please let me know if you need something else. Thanks a lot !

- I use version 1.0.0 of the `androidx.glance:glance-appwidget` lib, released a few days ago,
- I did not forget to add the `<receiver>` tag in my `AndroidManifest.xml`, as well as the required `android.appwidget.provider` xml file in my res/xml folder. I think I've correctly done everything that is mentioned on the [Glance setup](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/glance/setup) page given I have no problem adding the widget on my home screen in the first place,
- I use `SQLiteOpenHelper` under the hood to access my data, with a few helper classes of my creation on top of it, not using `Room` or any other ORM lib (I want to keep my application simple for now).
- Here is what my `provideGlance` method looks like :

```
    override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {

        val todoDbHelper = TodoDbHelper(context)
        val dbHelper = DbHelper(todoDbHelper.readableDatabase)
        val todoDao = TodoDao(dbHelper)
        val todos = todoDao.findAll()

        provideContent {
            TodoAppWidgetContent(todos)
        }
    }
```

The `todoDao.findAll()` returns a plain List (it relies on a helper function that runs on `Dispatchers.IO` so that the main thread is not blocked)

- I also don't use `Hilt` or any other DI lib.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I spent a few more hours searching and found my answer :

It turns out I was wrong assuming that the `provideGlance` method, or even the `provideContent` should be triggered again when calling any of the aforementioned `update` methods. You can fetch some initialization data in there but you cannot rely on it to keep your widget updated, it is only called when no *Glance session* is currently running (When first adding the widget / when time has passed since adding it). Instead you can (/should) rely on the **state** of your Glance Widget.

I think this concept of **Glance state** is very poorly explained in the guide, to say the least, so I'll give it a short try hoping to help people having the same problem as I did :

- When a **Glance session** is running, everytime any of the `GlanceAppWidget.update` methods are called from within the app, Glance will *recompose* your widget content using a fresh copy of the **Glance state**
- This **Glance state** must be defined beforehand, by providing a `GlanceStateDefinition` instance to your class extending **GlanceAppWidget**. This instance is responsible for providing the type (class) of your state, as well as the `DataStore` that Glance will use internally to get an updated version of the **Glance state**

A `DataStore` is an `interface` that provides two abstracts methods for getting and updating data (More info here : [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore)). There are 2 implementations provided, *Preferences DataStore* and *Proto DataStore*. The first one is intended to replace `SharedPreferences` as a mean to store key-value pairs, and the second can be used to store typed objects.

Most of the Glance tutorials I found on the web make use of the *Preferences DataStore* in their examples, but for my purpose I chose to implement my own version of a `DataStore` as a *readonly proxy* to my Dao object, as follows :

```
class TodoDataStore(private val context: Context): DataStore<List<TodoListData>> {
    override val data: Flow<List<TodoListData>>
        get() {
            val todoDbHelper = TodoDbHelper(context)
            val dbHelper = DbHelper(todoDbHelper.readableDatabase)
            val todoDao = TodoDao(dbHelper)
            return flow { emit(todoDao.findAll()) }
        }

    override suspend fun updateData(transform: suspend (t: List<TodoListData>) -> List<TodoListData>): List<TodoListData> {
        throw NotImplementedError("Not implemented in Todo Data Store")
    }
}
```

The state definition in my class extending `GlanceAppWidget` looks like this :

```
    override val stateDefinition: GlanceStateDefinition<List<TodoListData>>
        get() = object: GlanceStateDefinition<List<TodoListData>> {
            override suspend fun getDataStore(
                context: Context,
                fileKey: String
            ): DataStore<List<TodoListData>> {
                return TodoDataStore(context)
            }

            override fun getLocation(context: Context, fileKey: String): File {
                throw NotImplementedError("Not implemented for Todo App Widget State Definition")
            }
        }
```

Meaning I can now rely on the *state* of my Glance Widget instead of using my Dao class directly, by using the `currentState()` method :

```
    override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {
        provideContent {
            TodoAppWidgetContent(currentState())
        }
    }
```

It works like a charm now !

I intend to fill an issue regarding the lack of documentation regarding the **Glance state** and its relation to the concept of **Datastore** in the Glance guide.

Comment: Do you have a working copy of this widget that you like to share?

Comment: Holy cow. I can't thank you enough. Been trying to figure out using the "oficial" example and none seems to work. This is really helpful

Comment: You saved my day... This isn't documented anywhere