Issue with UI Rendering in GlanceAppWidget
I'm working on an Android app that includes a GlanceAppWidget to display notes. The widget should show a note's ID, and when a button is clicked, it updates the ID and reflects the change in the UI.
class NotesWidget : GlanceAppWidget() {
    override val stateDefinition = PreferencesGlanceStateDefinition
 
    override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {
        provideContent {
            GlanceTheme {
                val prefs = currentState<Preferences>()
                val noteId = prefs[intPreferencesKey("widgetNoteId")]
 
                Button(
                    text = noteId.toString(),
                    onClick = actionStartActivity<NotesWidgetActivity>()
                )
                println("Selected Note id $noteId")
            }
        }
    }
}
`
class NotesWidgetActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 
        val coroutineScope = MainScope()
        coroutineScope.launch {
            NotesWidgetReceiver.observeData(this@NotesWidgetActivity)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
 
class NotesWidgetReceiver : GlanceAppWidgetReceiver() {
    override val glanceAppWidget: GlanceAppWidget = NotesWidget()
 
    companion object {
        private val coroutineScope = MainScope()
 
        fun observeData(context: Context) {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                val noteId = (0..100).random()
                val glanceId = GlanceAppWidgetManager(context).getGlanceIds(NotesWidget::class.java).firstOrNull()
                if (glanceId != null) {
                    updateAppWidgetState(context, PreferencesGlanceStateDefinition, glanceId) { prefs ->
                        prefs.toMutablePreferences().apply {
                            this[intPreferencesKey("widgetNoteId")] = noteId
                        }
                    }
                    NotesWidget().update(context, glanceId)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I have implemented the NotesWidget, NotesWidgetActivity, and NotesWidgetReceiver classes. When the button in the widget is clicked, it updates the preference value for the note ID and logs the updated value. However, the UI does not reflect this change.
I expected the widget's UI to be updated with the new  ID after the preference is changed.
Console
2024-07-10 15:18:11.383 30519-30519 System.out              com.kin.easynotes.debug              I  Selected Note id null
2024-07-10 15:18:15.223 30519-30519 System.out              com.kin.easynotes.debug              I  Selected Note id 60 


I think your code might be throwing exception
as log shows noteId is printing as null.
then definitely noteId.toString() will throw NPE exception.
Try this way
 Button(text = "$noteId",onClick = actionStartActivity<NotesWidgetActivity>())
`

The button only displayed "null" without throwing any warnings or exceptions. I discovered that it works correctly with the default Android launcher but fails to function properly with custom launchers like Lawnchair.

Did it worked after changing the code or original code?
Actually that could be launcher's fault as well. I had hard time once with docomo launcher.
Have you tried with remoteviews?

The issue is specific to custom launchers and doesn't occur with the default Android launcher.I found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77088363/android-jetpack-glance-1-0-0-problems-updating-widget  that helped resolve this problem. You can find the code I used to fix it https://github.com/Kin69/EasyNotes/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/kin/easynotes/widget
